# Postgresql column referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to migrate a sqlite db to postgresql and i have a problem of foreign key. When i am trying to rake db:migrate on my pg database i got an error but it's working fine when i migrate on sqlite3

the error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "category_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "uitems" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_a560038df0"
FOREIGN KEY ("category_id")
  REFERENCES "categories" ("id")
```

db schema :

```
//db/schema.rb

...
 create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "categories", ["user_id"], name: "index_categories_on_user_id"

  create_table "categorizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "uitem_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "categorizations", ["category_id"], name: "index_categorizations_on_category_id"
  add_index "categorizations", ["uitem_id"], name: "index_categorizations_on_uitem_id"

create_table "uitems", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "uitems", ["article_id"], name: "index_uitems_on_article_id"
  add_index "uitems", ["user_id"], name: "index_uitems_on_user_id"


...
```

for my models :

```
//models/category.rb

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :uitems, :through => :categorizations,
           :class_name => "Uitem",
           :source => :uitem
  belongs_to :user
end


//models/categorization.rb

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :uitem
  belongs_to :category
end

 //models/uitem.rb

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations,
           :class_name => "Category",
           :source => :category
  has_many :opinions
  has_many :conversations
```

Do you find something unusual ? thanks for all the help you could give me

EDIT :

Problem solved, i had a old migration where i was asking to add a foreign key ( weird the migration worked fine on sqlite ) thx guys

Comment: and what error are you getting?

Comment: hello, i just edited my post

Comment: I don't know Rails, so maybe I'm missing something, but: `uitems` does not have a column named `category_id` so how do you expect that FK to work?

Comment: it's a many to many relationship, throught another model so i don't even know why pg is trying to add a foreign key. i just realized had a old migration where i was asking to add a foreignkey. Thx you for your comment. i just fixed my problem

Comment: because rails instruct it to do so.

Comment: What did you do to fix your problem? Can you post your own answer?